# How to concatenate JSX without encountering the "single root" issue with JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am wondering how to do this in JSX.  If you look at the code below, there are duplicated parts where `` <div className={`${cssComponentName}-container`}> `` is set being used to wrap the JSX.  How do I do this outside the if/else loop and a single return statement without encountering the "single root" issue with JSX.

```
buildComponent() {
const { element: {title, type, items }, name } = this.props;
const cssComponentName = name.toLowerCase();
if (type === 'string' || type === 'number') {
  return (
    <div className={`${cssComponentName}-container`}>
      <label htmlFor={name}>{title}</label>
      <input type="text" name={name} />
    </div>
  );
}

if (type === 'array') {
  return (
    <div className={`${cssComponentName}-container`}>
      <label htmlFor={name}>{title}</label>
      <select name={name}>
        { this.buildDropdown(items.enum, items.enumNames) }
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can be restructured in the following possible form with the use of a stateless function.

```
buildComponent() {
  const { element: {title, type, items }, name } = this.props;
  const cssComponentName = name.toLowerCase();

  const DivWrapper = (props) => {
    return (
      <div className={`${cssComponentName}-container`}>
        <label htmlFor={name}>{title}</label>
       {props.children}
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <DivWrapper>
    { (type === 'string' || type === 'number') ?
        <input type="text" name={name} /> :
      (type === 'array') ?
        <select name={name}>
          { this.buildDropdown(items.enum, items.enumNames) }
        </select> : null
    }
    </DivWrapper>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also try this approach:

```
buildElement(type, name, items) {
   if (type === 'string' || type === 'number') 
     return buildInput(name);
   else if (type === 'array')
         return  buildSelect(name, items);
}    

buildSelect(name, items) {
   return (<select name={name}>
            { this.buildDropdown(items.enum, items.enumNames) }
           </select>);
}    

buildInput(name) {
   return (<input type="text" name={name} />);
}    

buildComponent() {
  const { element: {title, type, items }, name } = this.props;
  const cssComponentName = name.toLowerCase();

  return (
    <div className={`${cssComponentName}-container`}>
    <label htmlFor={name}>{title}</label>
    {this.buildElement(type, name, items)}
    </div>
  );
}
```